# Stationary and nonstationary time series data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series

This question might sound trivial to some but I just got interested in time series analysis and have been reading up about it in the last couple of days. However, I am yet to understand the topic of identifying stationary/non-stationary time-series data. I generated some time-series data of two dimensions using some tool I found. Plotting it out, I get something like in this image: [image: 1] 
Looking at the plot, I think it shows some seasonalities (with the spike in the middle) and I would say its not stationary. However, doing the stationarity test as described in [Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-stationary-python/), it passed the stationarity test (the tests says its stationary) . Now, I'm confused maybe I didn't understand what seasons and trends means in time-series data. Am I wrong in thinking that the spikes hints at seasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the plot, your data looks like white noise, which is a type of stationary random data. A stationary time series has constant mean (in your case zero), variance, autocorrelation, etc. across time.

Seasonality is regular patterns that occur at specific calendar intervals within a year, for example quarterly, monthly, or daily patterns. Accordingly, large spikes in a plot do not usually indicate seasonality.

In contrast, the following time series (using R) exhibits an upward trend, monthly seasonality, and increasing variance:

```
plot(AirPassengers)
```

[image]

In sum, the AirPassengers time series is not stationary.